# Value or constructor is not defined

Tags: f#, fibonacci

I'm learning f# and I've got a pretty trivial problem that doesn't seem to make sense. I'm working on Project Euler problem 2 and I've got this:

```
let fib (x : BigInteger) (y : BigInteger) (max : BigInteger) = 
    let added = x + y
    if added > max then y
    else fib y (x + y) max
```

I've got the error at the recursive fib call:

> Value or constructor 'fib' is not defined

And I'm not sure why. Any help?

Comment: System.Int32.MaxValue >> 4000000, and "even-valued terms"

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Yea, I know it's not a correct or efficient solution to the problem at the moment. It's an iterative attempt. I'm just trying to fully get all of the syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `fib` is recursive function, it has to start with `let rec`.

Answer (score 7):

In F#, if you want to write a recursive function, you have to use [the `rec` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233232.aspx):

```
let rec fib (x : BigInteger) (y : BigInteger) (max : BigInteger) = 
    let added = x + y
    if added > max then y
    else fib y (x + y) max
```

That's because in F# under normal circumstances, you can only use  identifiers declared *before* the current code, unlike in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Talking of [Project Euler Problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2), you may consider instead of recursion going with `Seq.unfold`, which is very idiomatic and gives you all Fibonacci numbers at once:

```
let fibs = Seq.unfold (fun (current, next) ->
    Some(current, (next, current + next))) (1,2)
```

Now `fibs` represents lazy sequence of Fibonacci numbers :

```
>fibs;;
val it : seq<int> = seq[1; 2; 3; 5; ...]
```

And to make it of `BigInteger` just substitute `(1,2)` by `(1I,2I)`, although the solution allows you to stay within ordinary integers.

Comment: Even more idiomatic would be  let fibs = (1,2) |> Seq.unfold (fun (current, next) -> Some(current, (next, current + next)))

Comment: Interesting. I have just started reading about foldl/foldr but am still having trouble fully grasping their applications. I'll give this a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @SnOrfus: To see how this piece fits into the full solution context you may want to peek [here](http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/project-euler-problem-2/)

Comment: @GeneBelitski: Thanks. I will look at that once I write a working solution myself first :) I generally solve it on my own first, and then look for/at better solutions. I find I can really grasp it better that way.

Comment: fold and unfold are shortcuts for recursion with accumulators, I think that for learning is better to not use them, and do it manually instead