# Import Module fails - module is not defined and value or constructor not defined

Tags: f#

I want to use functions from a module inside the file BasicFunctions.fs.
After completing [f# hello world tutorial](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/languages/fsharp-hello-world-tutorial/modify) one next step is to work through [F# Tour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fsharp/tour).

The question [what is the equivalent of import in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171297/what-is-the-equivalent-of-import-in-f) and [printfn an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11732432/819887) helped a bit. The question [value or constructor not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643092/value-or-constructor-is-not-defined) seem to be not relevant for my case.

#### Attempt 1: change config to include second file

If i change my project configuration `myFsharpApp.fsproj` to this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="BasicFunctions.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I get the error: `FSC : error FS0225: Source file 'C:\dev\fsharp\myFSharpApp\BasicFunctions.fs' could not be found [C:\dev\fsharp\myFSharpApp\myFSharpApp.fsproj]`

But the file BasicFunctions.fs can be found under the path 'C:\dev\fsharp\myFSharpApp\BasicFunctions.fs'. So i do not understand why it is not found.

#### Attempt 2: change the config to this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Using `dotnet build` then returns

1. error FS0039: The namespace or module 'BasicFunctions' is not
   defined
2. error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a    ''a -> 'b -> 'c'
   but given a    ''a -> unit '    The type ''a -> 'b' does not match
   the type 'unit'
3. error FS0039: The value or constructor 'sampleFunction1' is not defined.[C:\dev\fsharp\myFSharpApp\myFSharpApp.fsproj]

Most of the code is copied from the [F# Tour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fsharp/tour). The difference is that i want to import functions from the file `BasicFunctions.fs` and want to print the result of `sampleFunction1 x = x*x + 3`

The code structure is the following

```
// BasicFunctions.fs
module BasicFunctions = 
    let sampleFunction1 x = x*x + 3

// Program.fs
module main =
    open BasicFunctions

// Define a new function to print a name.
let printGreeting name =
    printfn "Hello %s from F#!" name

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%d" BasicFunctions.sampleFunction1 3 // 12 expected
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

#### Questions

- What am i doing wrong in importing another file and its functions?
- What is wrong with `sampleFunction1 x = x*x + 3`?
- Why is `printfn "%d" 12` not working assuming that `sampleFunction1` returns an int with the value 12?

#### Screen of current code state

[image: screen of current code]

#### Content of fsproj

This is the content of `myFSharpApp.fsproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A top level module is defined without = and indentation
- Nothing
- Space is function application so in order to call like the with the right precedence you need paranthesis or pipe

So it becomes like below.

```
// BasicFunctions.fs
module BasicFunctions

let sampleFunction1 x = x * x + 3

// Program.fs
open BasicFunctions

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    sampleFunction1 3 
    |> printfn "%d" 
    0
```

Note that you can skip the open and reference the module directly. Both files needs to be included, in order.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="BasicFunctions.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I still get errors - see my attached screen above to see if i did miss anything.

Comment: How does your fsproj look like?

Comment: You need you include the files in order like your first attemp

Comment: After changing the proj-file running `dotnet build` gives the same error `FSC : error FS0225: Source file 'C:\dev\fsharp\myFSharpApp\BasicFunctions.fs' could not be found [C:\dev\fsharp\myFSharpApp\myFSharpApp.fsproj]`

Comment: Verify that file is correctly named. BasicFuntions is says in the editor instead of BasicFunctions

Comment: This was the cause. I overlooked that the file name was `BasicFuntions.fs` instead of `BasicFunctions.fs`